# set DateTimePicker value to empty on form load

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, datetimepicker

I'm using telerik Q3 2010 for winform, and I need to set DateTimePicker value to null on form load, I don't have NullableValue property to use it as mentioned [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/winforms/calendar-and-datetimepicker/datetimepicker-setting-itself-to-now-when-form-opens.aspx), because my control is from 2010 version, how can I do that using

```
 radDateTimePicker1.NullDate
```

I can't assign null value to it as it isn't nullable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly sure that you can do the following for that particular version:

`this.radDateTimePicker1.DateTimePickerElement.SetToNullValue();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the `DateTimePicker` value to the empty. But just to show reset value, you can set it to current value using `DateTime.Today`.